# Error Handling - NodeJS Express.Router - WrapperAsync

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, exception, async-await

I am a bit lost on how should i handle errors on my app using async/await.
The problem is that i am having in each function of my userController a try/catch to handle this. 
I read many places that you can wrap your function in a helper function like this:

```
function wrapAsync(fn) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // Make sure to `.catch()` any errors and pass them along to the `next()`
    // middleware in the chain, in this case the error handler.
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
}

router.get('/users/:id', wrapAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
   /* 
     if there is an error thrown in getUserFromDb, asyncMiddleware
     will pass it to next() and express will handle the error;
   */
const user = await getUserFromDb({ id: req.params.id })
   res.json(user);
}));
```

I have structured my NodeJS app this way:

**Routes:**

```
export class Routes {
static init(app: express.Application, router: express.Router) {
    app.use('/api', router);

    // Here add all the endpoints
    UserRoutes.init(router);
    // End of endpoints
 }}
```

**UserRoutes:**

```
export class UserRoutes {
static init(router: express.Router) {

    router
        .route('/user/startVerification')
        .post(UserController.startVerification);

    router
        .route('/user/verify')
        .post(UserController.verifyUser);

    router
        .route('/user/register')
        .put(UserController.registerUser);
}
```

**UserController:**

```
export class UserController {
    static async startVerification(req: any, res: express.Response) {}

    static async registerUser(req: any, res: express.Response, next: 
     express.NextFunction) {}

   static async verifyUser(req: any, res: express.Response) {}
}
```

I want to apply this pattern on my app. I tryed to use it in different ways but with no result. In my context, how can i wrap this function on my routes?

Comment: .post(wrapAsync(UserController.startVerification)) doesn't work?

Comment: Doing that @RobertMoskal, before i hit the endpoint the function is stopping on the wrapper function. But after deleted the try/catch block the flow do not stop on the catch of the wrapper :(

Comment: My fault, now is working. But i still have a question, i have to wrap ALL my functions with this function? Is there a way to not repeat logic and easily wrap my all routes with this wrapper? (In my case, wrapping  at top level on the Routes class)

Comment: That sounds like a good question to ask here!